# Sudden disappearance of icons on Ubuntu 20.04 after choosing the icon pack

Tags: icons

I am running Ubuntu 20.04, I downloaded colloid icon pack to customize soon after choosing the icon pack all my icons and apps disappeared. I couldn't even open my terminal and folders except chrome...can anyone help me in sorting out this..

Here it is, how they are after choosing the icon pack.

[image: Missing icons]

Answer (score 0):

I tried this icon pack for myself as well, and it did the same thing that it did to you - I couldn't open terminal and any apps that didn't have any icon. The way that I fixed it was by opening the TTY Console by pressing `Ctrl+Alt+F3` and then removing the folder that contains the icons. (In my case I had to cd into .icons folder and then I typed `rm -r Colloid-gray`), So all you need to do is login into your TTY Console, cd into the directory which the colloid icon theme is located and type `rm -r <directory-name>`. After succesfully removing the folder, you can now return to your desktop by pressing `Alt+F2`.
Hope that helped and good luck!